"invalid_client" Error for 'Sign in with Apple'
here is I followed step on my apple developer account.
Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles:

App Createion >> Identifiers:

Identifiers >> choose "App IDs" >> click in +(Add) sign near by "Identifiers" title
Register a new identifier >> choose "App IDs" >> Continue >> Select a type "App" >>

Description: App signup
Bundle ID >> choose Explicit : app.testnew.com

Select >> Sign In with Apple and continue for register





Service Creation >> Identifiers:

Identifiers >> choose "Services IDs" >> click in +(Add) sign near by "Identifiers" title
Register a new identifier >> choose "Services IDs" >> Continue

Description: App signup

Bundle ID: app.testnew.com.signup

"Sign In with Apple" >> Configure >> click

choose "Primary App ID" >> App signup (FWE9UH46PJ.app.testnew.com)
"Website URLs" >>

"Domains and Subdomains":

staging.tadarab.com
app.tadarab.com


"Return URLs":

https://app.tadarab.com/wp-json/api/auth/apple_callback




Continue and Save it.




Keys Creation:

Click on Keys >> click in +(Add) sign near by "Keys" title
Key Name: App signup

select "Sign in with Apple" >> click "Configure"

Configure Key >> choose "Primary App ID": App signup (FWE9UH46PJ.app.testnew.com)

show message Grouped App IDs - App signup (FWE9UH46PJ.app.testnew.com.signup)


Save and Downloaded file MyAuth_KEYCODE.p8

Name: App signup
Key ID: 39QJ7GJ1A9





Team ID I found from my Setting >> Membership Details:
Team ID: FWE9UH46PJ

here is my Front-end code which is in staging domain. (https://www.staging.tadarab.com/)
Front-end code:
<AppleLogin  
  clientId="app.testnew.com.signup"
  redirectURI="https://app.tadarab.com/wp-json/api/auth/apple_callback"
  callback={responseApple}
  responseType={"code"} 
  responseMode={"query"}  
  usePopup={false}
  render={(renderProps) => (
    <div
      onClick={renderProps.onClick}
      className={`${styles["apple-login-button"]} ${renderProps.disabled ? styles["disabled"] : ""}`}
    >
      <AppleIcon color="white" />
      انشاء حساب بواسطة آبل
    </div>
  )}
/>


Backend code:
function apple_signup_test($request) {
    $APPLE_KEY_ID="39QJ7GJ1A9";
    $KEY_CONTENT = file_get_contents((dirname(__DIR__)."/MyAuth_KEYCODE.p8"));    
    $APPLE_TEAM_ID="FWE9UH46PJ";
    $APPLE_CLIENT_ID="app.testnew.com.signup";
    $SECRET_KEY = generate_apple_client_secret($APPLE_CLIENT_ID, $APPLE_KEY_ID, $APPLE_TEAM_ID, $KEY_CONTENT);

    $request_pera = $request->get_params();
    $code = $request->get_param('code');

    $response = wp_remote_post('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token', [
        'body' => [
            'client_id' => $APPLE_CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret' => $SECRET_KEY,
            'code' => $code,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://app.tadarab.com/wp-json/api/auth/apple_callback'
        ]
    ]);
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    echo "Code: {$token}\n\n\n";
    echo "Response: ";
    print_r($body);
    exit;
}

function generate_apple_client_secret($client_id,$key_id,$team_id,$key_content) {
    $header = base64UrlEncode(json_encode([
        'alg' => 'ES256',
        'kid' => $key_id // Your Key ID
    ]));

    $payload = base64UrlEncode(json_encode([
        'iss' => $team_id, // Your Team ID
        'iat' => time(),
        'exp' => time() + 86400 * 180, // 180 days expiration
        'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
        'sub' => $client_id // Your Client ID
    ]));
    $unsignedToken = $header . '.' . $payload;
    $privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($key_content);
    if (!$privateKey) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        echo 'Failed to read private key: ' . $error['message'];
        exit;
    }
    $signature = '';
    if (openssl_sign($unsignedToken, $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256)) {
        $signedToken = $unsignedToken . '.' . base64UrlEncode($signature);
        return $signedToken;
    } else {
        echo "Failed to sign the token.\n";
        exit;
    }
}

function base64UrlEncode($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}


https://www.staging.tadarab.com/sign-up
When I click on Apple login button, it's redirect me to "Sign in with Apple" after that redirect back me to the my redirect URL:
https://app.tadarab.com/wp-json/api/auth/apple_callback?code=cd74429298a97445186a66a2a1eab92ee.0.rrrzz.gp6KwnCP9q0KOUwaK-9ZBQ
I show the result on this URL:
Code: cd74429298a97445186a66a2a1eab92ee.0.rrrzz.gp6KwnCP9q0KOUwaK-9ZBQ
Response: {"error":"invalid_client"}

Here is what I have tried so far:

I created different apps, services, and keys.

I used different domains and generated new SSL certificates.

I tested the integration across PHP, React, and Ruby on Rails.

I tested the generated secrete on https://jwt.io/ and When I add public & private key, it's show me "Signature Varified" (The public and private key generated using the MyAuth_KEYCODE.p8 file.)


When the client/app/key details are incorrect, I receive expected errors like:

"redirect_uri mismatch. The code was not issued to this URL."

"client_id mismatch. The code was not issued to this domain."


However, when everything is set correctly, the error message changes to "invalid_client".
Could you please provide guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Any help or insight you could offer would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.
